# Update collection using email inplace of _Id as the unique Id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have 2 collection tables that only share emails as the unique ids of these 2 tables. The first one is `Meteor.users()` and `SchoolStudents`. I want to update the SchoolStudents collection based on the user's email. Though I have successfully updated using _id but the update isn't working using email as the Id. What's the better approach?

In this, it returned a success feedback but no update is made to the record. `Bert.alert('Record updated successfully', 'success', 'growl-top-right');`

Client code:

```
let user = Meteor.user();
let studentemail = user && user.emails && user.emails[0].address;
   if (studentemail) {
        console.log(studentemail);
        Meteor.call('UpdateUser', studentemail, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
          Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
          return false;
        } else {
            Bert.alert('Record updated successfully', 'success', 'growl-top-right');
         }
      })
  }
```

Server method

```
SchoolStudents.update({useremail: studentemail}, {$set: {'status.active': true, 'status.activedate': new Date()}});
```

This is a sample document from the *SchoolStudents* collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "xgxZJFRkXGhHmHupY",
    "firstname" : "Kehinde",
    "lastname" : "Adeoya",
    "middlename" : "Adekusibe",
    "username" : "ken10ward",
    "password" : "PvyLwY9d",
    "useremail" : "kadeoya@appzonegroup.com",
    "studentclass" : "ss8",
    "dateofbirth" : "9-Mar-00",
    "gender" : "f",
    "ethinicity" : "black",
    "mobile" : "8023472442",
    "address" : "7 Abrahamoivc",
    "city" : "bolson",
    "lg" : "loveland",
    "state" : "ekiti",
    "country" : "Ukraine",
    "registra" : "kadeoya",
    "status" : {
        "active" : false,
        "activedate" : null
    },
    "userId" : "n5rqFSHbhm7zqADyB",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-05T18:45:14.877Z"),
    "friendlySlugs" : {
        "slug" : {
            "base" : "kehinde-adeoya",
            "index" : 5
        }
    },
    "slug" : "kehinde-adeoya-5"
}
```

This is the server update code:

```
UpdateUser: function (studentemail) {
    check(studentemail, String);
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
        Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
        return false;
    } else {
        SchoolStudents.update({useremail: studentemail}, {status: {active: true, activedate: new Date()}}, { upsert: true });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `user && user.emails && user.emails[0].address` is doing what you think it's doing? Because `user` is of course going to be an "object" and that's not a valid argument to the query, and `user.emails` would appear to be an array which also would not be valid. The final would appear to be a singular value, but if that was not defined then you still get nothing. I think you meant ` `user || user.emails || user.emails[0].address`, but it still suffers from the same problems even though the logical assignment makes more sense.

Comment: Yes. I printed the email on the console and it's fine. so those line of code works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Really? Because `{} && [] && undefined` will not work fine at all. If you are not matching anything to update, then the problem is the value you are supplying.

Comment: Where is the `$set` in your *server update code*?

Answer (score -1):

As it has been pointed to you, you're using `user && user.emails && user.emails[0].address` construct wrong way.

I suggest you to use this template to do things like that:

```
let studentemail;
try {
  studentemail = user.emails[0].address.valueOf();
} catch (e) {
  studentemail = null;
}
if (studentemail != null) {
  ...
}
```

This way you can omit numerous checks, like `user != null` and `user.emails != null` and `user.emails.length > 0` etc and it will be guaranteed that in your `studentemail` variable you will get *either* `null` *or* user email address.

**Added:** User email address *could* be `undefined`, that's why you need `!= null` check (non-strict). It will be `false` if variable is `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Styx, thanks. Though this may pose to be problem but sincerely only the email got printed and not all user object when I printed it on the console. It means it's getting the right thing. I suppose my update query could be the problem. Maybe you can intelligently review this query. I'm not sure I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: @kehinde Could you show the schema of `SchoolStudents` collection and the code where it's initialized?

Comment: I have updated the question with the schema. Thanks. God bless.

Comment: @kehinde And server code with `UpdateUser` method as well, please

Comment: Thanks. @Styx, i have updated the question with the full code for update.

Comment: @kehinde Ahha, your `UpdateUser` method has an error. Regardless of its `Meteor.userId()` check it will never return error to client. There should be `throw new Meteor.Error('auth-error', 'Not authorized');` instead of just `return false`. Try it.

Comment: @kehinde They seem like right, though I'd recommend to add index on `useremail` field

Comment: What do you mean by index? You mean id?